# RabbitMQ Cluster : unable to connect to nodes : nodedown

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq in two machines in linux OS.And they all worked well. Then I run the command:rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@gz2, it's not work.And the error info :

Error: unable to connect to nodes [rabbit@gz2]: nodedown

attempted to contact: [rabbit@gz2]

rabbit@gz2:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on gz2
- epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
- TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
- suggestion: hostname mismatch?
- suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
- suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

Comment: hosts config is ok(ping gz2 say it ok),and cookie is the same with other node,using this command  md5sum /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie. I has search many answer 
with losts of time but it not the same problem.

Comment: The log file is empty(/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@VM-16-7-ubuntu.log). Reboot machine it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

> suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?

You need to ensure both RabbitMQ nodes are using the same cookie file. Copy the file `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` from one node to the other, then restart RabbitMQ on the node to which you copied the file. You will be able to create a cluster after that.

Clustering and the Erlang cookie is documented [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie).

Answer (score 0):

In my case under Windows 64 Pro.

1. Open your `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie` with your text editor and copy the cookie string in your clipboard.
2. Open your RabbitMQ command prompt (sbin dir) and paste the copied cookie after the **--erlang-cookie** parameter i.e `rabbitmq-diagnostics --erlang-cookie "PASTE YOUR COOKIE HERE" status` for example
   `rabbitmq-diagnostics --erlang-cookie "WPYNGBZFUXHSWPCOYSDN" status`
3. if it works without errors, just copy the cookie file from `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie` to `C:\Users\<YOUR USER NAME>\` and you are ready to go without using the parameter `--erlang-cookie "WPYNGBZFUXHSWPCOYSDN"`. Replace the  with the actual username you logged to your OS i.e `C:\Users\admin\`